# There exists a lattice point $(a,b)$ whose distance from every *visible* point is greater than $n$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

**Question**- A lattice point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ is called *visible* if $gcd(x,y)=1$. Prove that given a positive integer $n$, there exists a lattice point $(a,b)$ whose distance from every *visible* point is greater than $n$.

I am totally nowhere near progress on this. I was thinking of trying pigeon hole principle, but cant find any appropriate candidate pigeons. Please give any hints to start.

Comment: Anyone please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from Theorem 7.3 in the book “Mathematical Journeys,” by Peter D. Schumer. The proof, which uses the Chinese remainder theorem, can be seen on Google Books [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=tV__OQ8LZcgC&lpg=PA69&ots=zFyk4BO6CV&dq=lattice%20points%20invisible%20squares&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q&f=false) or (summarized) by hovering over the spoiler paragraph below.

Schumer constructs an $n\times n$ square of invisible lattice points as follows. (You can choose $(a,b)$ at the center of such a square of side $2n$.)

The proof goes like this:

> Arrange the first $n^2$ primes in an $n\times n$ array and denote by $m_i$ the product across the $i$-th row and by $M_i$ the product down the $i$-th column. Then consider two systems of congruences: The system $x\equiv -i \mod m_i$ and the system $y\equiv -i\mod M_i$. Modulo $P=\prod m_i=\prod M_i$, these systems have unique solutions $x\equiv_P a$ and $y\equiv_P b$ (by the Chinese Reminder Theorem). Then the square with lower left corner $(a+1,b+1)$ and upper right corner $(a+n,b+n)$ contains no visible lattice points, because for any integers $i,j$ between $1$ and $n$, both $a+i$ and $b+j$ will be divisible by the prime $p$ in row $i$ and column $j$ of the array of primes.